# side menu with submenu

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want the menu to have the same effect as this menu from this page http://store.anumberofnames.org/ when someone clicks on the shop link the submenu to drop down and when they click on information the shop link to close and the information submenu to dropdown and also when they click on a category on the sebmenus i want the link that they selected to be highlighted, below is the html and css code i have

html

```
 <div id="menu">
<nav>
 <ul>

  <li>
    <a href="#">SHOP</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">T-SHIRT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">KNIT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SHIRT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">PANTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ACCESSORY</a></li>
    </ul>
  <li><a href="#">INFORMATION</a>
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">NEWSLETTER</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">LEGAL</a></li>
    </ul>
    </LI>
   </ul>
  </nav> 
 </div>    
</div>
```

css

```
#menu nav > ul > li > ul {
display: none;
text-align: right;
}

#menu nav a {
display: block;  
}

#menu nav > ul > li > a {
display: block;  
border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;  
}

#menu nav > ul > li:hover > a {
border-bottom: 3px solid white;  
}



#menu nav ul li  {
font-size: 11px;
top:106px;
list-style-type: none;
text-decoration: none;
color:#ffffff;
line-height: 19px;

}

nav a {
color:rgb(153, 153, 153);
text-decoration: none;
}
#mainSidebar {
display: block;
font-family:arial;
font-size: 11px;
font-stretch: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: normal;
height: 450px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
min-height: 750px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
position: fixed;
text-transform: uppercase;
vertical-align: baseline;   
}
#menu nav ul {
padding: 0px;
line-height: 11.5px;
margin-top: 0px;    
padding-bottom: 5px;
width: 143px;
padding-top: 5px;   
}
#menu nav ul li a:hover{
color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That uses jQuery. You can do it using the two functions: `slideDown()` and `slideUp()`, or using a single function: `slideToggle()`:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#menu nav > ul > li > ul").hide();
  $("#menu nav > ul > li > a").click(function() {
    if (!$(this).next("ul").is(":visible")) {
      $("#menu nav > ul > li > ul").slideUp();
      $(this).next("ul").slideDown();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
#menu nav > ul > li > ul {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
#menu nav a {
  display: block;
}
#menu nav > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}
#menu nav > ul > li:hover > a {
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
}
#menu nav ul li {
  font-size: 11px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 19px;
}
nav a {
  color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
  text-decoration: none;
}
#mainSidebar {
  display: block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 450px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  min-height: 750px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
#menu nav ul {
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 11.5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: 143px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
#menu nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">SHOP</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">T-SHIRT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">KNIT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SHIRT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PANTS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ACCESSORY</a></li>
        </ul>
      <li><a href="#">INFORMATION</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.google.com">NEWSLETTER</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">LEGAL</a></li>
        </ul>
      </LI>
    </ul>
  </nav> 
</div>
```

Comment: both submenu stay open , i want one to close when the other opens

Comment: @ISRAEL That's easy. I am updating the answer for you.

Comment: @ISRAEL I have made it into an accordion. Have a look.